# NodeJs: Run Mysql queries synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql2

I'm using NodeJS and mysql2 to store data in my database. but their are times when I need to perform database saves synchronously, like this example:

```
if(rent.client.id === 0){
    //Save client
    connection.query('INSERT INTO clients (name, identity, licence, birthDate, address, phoneNumber, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
                     [/*Array of values*/],
                     function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //Retrieve client id to use it in the next database save
        rent.client.id = results.insertId;
    })
}

//Save rent
connection.query('INSERT INTO rents (deliveryDate, returnDate, gasLevel, deliveryPoint, deliveryPrice, unitPrice, state, clientID, carID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
                 [/*Array of values that contain the last inserted id clients*/],
                 function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('rent saved', results);
})
```

So how can I perform these two database saves synchronously. I don't think that doing it in the following manner is good code:

```
connection.query(queryString, 
                 [queryValues],
                 function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query(queryString, 
                     [queryValues],
                     function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('rent saved', results);
    })

})
```

So what kind of solutions do you propose?

Comment: What makes you think you need to do these synchronously? Nothing in the code in the question suggests that's the case.

Comment: Unless your MySQL connector provides a synchronous way to do this, you can't do it synchronously. You cannot (reasonably) make a function that does its work asynchronously (like `query`) do its work synchronously. (The *unreasonable* way involves spawning a child process via `execSync`.)

Comment: Please note that `if (err) throw err;` is a bug in a NodeJS-style callback. It will not do anything useful. In particular, it won't make your function calling `query` (in the example above) throw.

Comment: Okay, I do understand I can't do this synchronously. then how can I accomplish my objective? When I run my code the rent does get saved before the first query has returned the client `Id`. And I do believe that you agree with me that the nested query is bad code.

Comment: Async is Node.js most powerful features, it's why it can handle thousands of concurrent connections without breaking a sweat.  One disadvantage is that in the past you had all this callback mess.  Good news is node.js now has full support for `Promises` and `async / await`..  Read up on these and you will find the above code will be much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think that doing it in the following manner is good code

It isn't, but only because of the

```
if (err) throw err;
```

part, which will not do anything useful. (It certainly won't make your function making these `query` calls throw an exception; it can't, you function has *already returned*. All it does is throw an exception from the callback; `query` probably ignores it.)

Other than that, it's the correct way to do this with NodeJS-style callbacks. More specifically:

```
function myFunctionToDoThisWork(callback) {
    connection.query(queryString1, 
                     [queryValues1],
                     function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        connection.query(queryString2, 
                         [queryValues2],
                         function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('rent saved', results);
        });
    });
}
```

There are couple of things you can do to make that code easier to maintain:

One is to use promises, which you can use on any vaguely-recent version of Node (or via an `npm` module). First we'd give ourselves a Promise-enabled version of `query`. In Node v8 and above, you can do that like this:

```
const promisify = require("utils").promisify;
// ...
const queryPromise = promisify(connection.query.bind(connection));
```

Alternately there's the [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify) `npm` module, or really this basic version is really trivial:

```
function promisify(f) {
    return function() {
        var t = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            args.push(function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
            f.apply(t, args);
         });
    };
}
```

Then:

```
function myFunctionToDoThisWork() {
    return queryPromise(queryString1, [queryValues1])
        .then(() => {
            return queryPromise(queryString2, [queryValues2]);
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('rent saved', results);
        });
    });
}
```

then consume it via:

```
myFunctionToDoThisWork().then(/*...*/).catch(/*...*/);
```

On Node v8 and higher, you can take that further with `async` and `await`:

```
async function myFunctionToDoThisWork() {
    await queryPromise(queryString1, [queryValues1]);
    await queryPromise(queryString2, [queryValues2]);
    console.log('rent saved', results);
}
```

If you call it from an `async` function, you'd consume it via `await`. If calling it from a non-`async` function, you consume it just like the promise version above (via `then`).

Comment: If you are using `node-mysql2`，promise support is already built-in, there is no need to do the promisify step.

Comment: @RicoChen: Good point, `promisify` is really a temporary measure while waiting for `npm` modules to provide native support. Hopefully something we won't be using often at all within just a year or two.

Answer (score 0):

mysql2 has promise support built in ([docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper)). 
Just import "mysql2/promise" in stead of "mysql2", and
all the relevant methods return promises:

```
import * as mysql from "mysql2/promise";

async function duStuff() {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(...);
    await connection.query(...);
}
```